# Fine semantic differences between "thus" and "therefore"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, connotation, discourse-markers

I have seen a few Q&A's with this title but none really reflects my question. I am aware both are adverbs and so forth and how they syntactically can be used equivalently, but what about connotations? Are there places where "therefore" is preferred over thus and vice versa? Are there any fine differences in usage?

Comment: And then there's *hence* ...

Comment: @hippietrail And then there's Maude https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWUD7MBdDuo

Answer (score 49):

*Therefore* is used in introducing a conclusion that follows from what has been said previously.

> You are drunk, and that makes you incapable of operating machinery. Therefore you shouldn't fly a plane.

*Thus* means *in this way*. For example:

> He waved his arms around thus. *(speaker waves arms around in demonstration)*

Extending that meaning, it can be used to introduce the intended consequences of an action:

> I intend to eat less, and thus lose weight.

And stretching that meaning further it can, like *therefore*, indicate the conclusion of an argument:

> Trees are plants, and plants are living. Thus we can see that trees are living.

To me at least, in the cases where they have the same basic meaning, the effect of *therefore* and *thus* is slightly different: *therefore* emphasises that the conclusion is an inescapable logical consequence of what goes immediately before; *thus* puts more focus on the argument as a whole and the way it leads towards the conclusion.

Comment: Brilliant. I googled the difference because I had a feeling that each word emphasised an argument and its conclusion in different ways, but I couldn't quite put my finger on it. Your explanation, however, was just perfect.

Comment: It seems to me that it should be `He waved his arms around thusly.` Perhaps that is a dialectal difference ´_`? Also, what does "thus" mean in `thus far`? I would say it means something different than "in this way". Comments?

Comment: @mac _Thus_ and _thusly_ are equivalent when the meaning is ‘in this way’. _Thusly_ arose in the 18th or 19th century as a hypercorrection (like saying “He runs fastly” instead of “He runs fast”), but is now generally considered fairly standard.

Comment: Re "*Therefore you shouldn't fly a plane*": Yet <thus> also sounds ok, no?

Comment: @Pacerier: Did you read the whole answer? :-)

Answer (score 10):

From American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition

**thus**

- In this manner: *Lay the pieces out **thus**.*<sup>1</sup>
- To a stated degree or extent; so. <sup>2</sup>
- Therefore; consequently: ***Thus***<sup>3</sup> it was necessary for me to resign.
- For example: *Few of the nation's largest cities are state capitals; **thus**<sup>4</sup> neither New York nor Chicago is the seat of its state's government.*

<sup>1</sup> not same: you cannot say *lay the pieces out therefore*.
<sup>2</sup> not same: you cannot say *we've discussed three topics therefore far*
<sup>3</sup> this meaning is the same
<sup>4</sup> not same: replacing it with therefore makes it a conclusion out of an example.

Comment: What about the instances where 'therefore' can be used but 'thus' cannot?

Comment: @Mitch, on that side it is much more simple as therefore has only "1. For that reason or cause; consequently or hence."

Answer (score 4):

> It is raining (A), therefore the grass is wet (B).

- **therefore** emphasizes that A was the cause of B.

> It is raining (A), thus the grass is wet (B).

- **thus** means that A results in B, but does not emphasize that A was the cause of B.

## Notes

A sidenote about German: after discussing this with an Austrian, we concluded that:

folglich/in folge -> thus

deshalb -> therefore

also see:

- [Can "so" and "thus" be used interchangeably?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128813/can-so-and-thus-be-used-interchangeably)
- [Avoiding stuffy language: "Therefore", "Thus"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230703/avoiding-stuffy-language-therefore-thus)
- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Aristotle

Comment: That’s the subordinate clause, not the matrix clause. I should perhaps have been more precise and said that _thus_ and _therefore_ are not used in the apodosis of a conditional construction, but in this case, the upshot is the same. “If I ate poisonous French fries, I would therefore get sick”, with _therefore_ in the matrix clause, is ungrammatical. My comment was related to the original form of your answer, which had “If A, thus/therefore B”. That has since been edited out, so I’ll delete my comment as it’s no longer relevant.