# Can "so" and "thus" be used interchangeably?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Example:

> Although Karla had been in this area many times before, this was the
>   first time she'd seen this coffee shop. So she decided to give it a try.

Can I use **thus** instead of **so** in the example above? Would that change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: It is logical and grammatical, but very stuffy (and not very common) in US English. You might find *thus* used this way in formal argument, but not common speech or informal writing.

Comment: I use both equally, in more formal explanations on ELU. Never in a less formal setting. The tone of your text is far from being formal enough to warrant _thus_.

Comment: There is a slight difference in meaning. ‘So’ in this case is more or less equivalent to ‘as such’ or ‘as a result’, where ‘thus’ is synonymous with ‘therefore’ or ‘for that reason’. One emphasises the reasoning, the other the outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. 'Thus' or 'hence' are a bit more formal; words more likely to be found in essays etc. 'So' in this sense is more conversational.

Comment: But thus is so much closer to the language of Milton and Shakespeare ;)

Comment: I mean t'say, wha' yer on abaut,mplungian, anyfink goes dunnit? Should we maintain a high standard of English prose, or should we just accept whatever gets spoken in the street as 'English'?