# Avoiding stuffy language: "Therefore", "Thus"

Tags: synonyms, formality, writing-style

In my thesis, I'm using "thus" and "therefore" a lot.  This is repetitive and it sounds stuffy.  Is there any alternative which sounds a bit more relaxed but is acceptable in scientific writing?  "So" would be too colloquial, I suppose.

Example for "thus:"

> Later in life, neural responses to sensory input become highly
> differentiated, as do overt reactions. Thus, it can be assumed that
> neurons adapt their responses mediated by experience...
>
> The neural responses used by the SC to localize stimuli are stochastic.
> Thus, the SC’s task can be described as a statistical inference
> problem: ...

(Sorry, I didn't find any examples for "therefore" which would make sense outside of the thesis.)

Comment: "*As a consequence*" (or *consequentially*, though that strays back into stuffy territory again), "*in turn*", "*in light of this*", "*given that*", etc. in other words: use phrases of more than one word, doing so gives you opportunities for both variety and flexibility.

Comment: 'Is there any alternative which sounds a bit more relaxed but is acceptable in scientific writing?' is possibly asking for the impossible.  I'd say Dan's suggestions are hardly 'more relaxed'. There are style guides dedicated to scientific writing. If your institution has one, see if it mentions register (it almost certainly will). Otherwise, check in the style guides that are available from other institutions. This is really 'primarily opinion based', and not a suitable question for ELU (though obviously an important issue).

Comment: It seems to me your second example is probably just a simple "misuse" of ***thus*** anyway (is it really true that the second statement inexorably and only follows from the first?). But even if such a relationship *does* exist between consecutive statements, it's often completely unnecessary to explicitly convey this using [conjunctive adverbs](http://www.talkenglish.com/Grammar/conjunctive-adverbs.aspx). You know your reader isn't an idiot; he doesn't need to be "spoon-fed" from every sentence to the next one.

Comment: My advice: don't worry about using 'thus' and go ahead and use 'thusly' as well for extra points!

Comment: Every reader will have a different opinion about what makes prose stuffy. In my view, too-frequent recourse to _thus_ and _therefore_ is undesirable mainly because it comes across as unduly concerned with emphasizing the continuity and logical seamlessness of the text. But as a tool promoting stuffiness, such overuse has nothing on continual recourse to "it can be assumed that," ""X can be described as," etc. Occasionally replacing phrases of the type "Thus it can be assumed that neurons" with "Clearly neurons" "Evidently neurons," "Presumably neurons," etc., can be like opening a window.

Comment: It's okay to have stuffy language for a thesis. Theses are intentionally full of stuffy, academic language anyway. For other situations like marketing copy for example, I'd avoid the stuffy language.

Comment: In technical writing, being precise far outweighs seeming stuffy.

Comment: @JamesTaylor: your irony (I hope that's what it is) may confuse non-native speakers coming here for help.

Comment: Others arguing that one shouldn't worry about stuffiness in scientific writing: Yes, in scientific writing clarity is more important than style, but no, that doesn't mean style doesn't matter.  Where's the value in scientific writing if nobody can read it without falling asleep over it?

Comment: I'd worry more about the clarity and logic of the neuroscience above. E.g., the first assumption doesn't logically follow (it could be biological development only, not only experience-driven), and is vague (adapt their responses on what time scale? I mean, they adapt on a ms to ms basis based on inputs). Also not sure what you mean by "overt reactions". Last, just because the actvity of inputs to SC are stochastic doesn't necessarily warrant describing it as a statistical inference problem, does it? Can't it just merely be summing inputs over certain time windows? (Or is that equivalent?)

Comment: @JohannesBauer "Where's the value in scientific writing if nobody can read it without falling asleep over it?" - Be careful. This sounds like a step towards Idiocracy. Neither "thus" nor "therefore" is stuffy; it's literate and professional. Personally, I'm more alert and captivated when reading clear, precise text, than I am when, say, reading a slew of YouTube comments written in casual language. Your real issue is the repetition. Overuse of the same few words will sound grating and uneducated. That doesn't mean you should opt for overly casual language, especially not in scientific text!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the methods presented in [RegDwigнt's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/230705) — using synonyms and simply removing the words — two other techniques for avoiding such repetition come to mind.

Replacing "thus" or "therefore" in the conclusion with "since" or "because" in the clause presenting the evidence is perhaps the most straightforward. This technique works better with shorter statements of evidence.

> Since neural responses to sensory input, as well as overt reactions, become highly differentiated later in life, it can be assumed that neurons adapt their responses mediated by experience...
>
> Because the neural responses used by the SC to localize stimuli are stochastic, the SC’s task can be described as a statistical inference problem: ...

The second technique would be to use a verb that includes the logical inference such as "indicate", "imply", "show", "demonstrate", or even "allows". Using a participle avoids the need for an explicit subject, but "this" or "such evidence" are adequate subjects. (In fact, "such evidence" might be preferred when the evidence is extensive.)

> Neural responses to sensory input become highly differentiated later in life, as do overt reactions, indicating that neurons adapt their responses mediated by experience...
>
> The neural responses used by the SC to localize stimuli are stochastic. This allows the SC’s task to be described as a statistical inference problem: ...

This can include reversing the order of evidence and conclusion.

> That neurons adapt their responses mediated by experience can be concluded from the fact that neural responses to sensory input, as well as overt reactions, become highly differentiated later in life.
>
> The SC's task can be treated as a statistical inference problem by recognizing the stochastic nature of the neural responses used by the SC to localize stimuli: ...

(The latter rephrasing is clearly problematic since the colon indicates that a stronger binding to "statistical inference problem" is desired. However, it provides the useful example of "recognize" replacing "show", changing the subject from the evidence to the observer allows further variety in verbs.)

Comment: Incidentally, this kind of question is also on topic on the [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com/), which could use more non-fiction questions.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Writers.  My question would probably have been even more on topic there than here.
Accepting this, because this answer contains the most concrete advice.

Answer (score 23):

There are many synonyms that a thesaurus of your choice will be quick to provide. However, consider this:

There is no reason to have the *thus*es in there in the first place. Remove them completely, and you're still conveying the same information. It is quite obvious that each of the sentences logically flows from the previous one.

> Later in life, neural responses to sensory input become highly differentiated, as do overt reactions. It can be assumed that neurons adapt their responses mediated by experience...
>
> The neural responses used by the SC to localize stimuli are stochastic. The SC’s task can be described as a statistical inference problem: ...

You don't need to expressly connect each and every sentence with its predecessor — it already *is* connected simply by means of being the next sentence in the same paragraph.

Generally speaking, whenever you wish to avoid using any particular word, start by *simply not using it* and then see what it gets you. More often than not, it will be enough.

Comment: There's a point to these *"thus's"*; they show cause and effect. But by rewriting, you can use *"because"* and *"since"* for the same thing, which are less stuffy words.

Comment: @Peter I'll give you the second one perhaps. In the first case, the cause and effect are obvious to me either way. But yeah, if you think there really *is* a point to using a word, then there *is* no way to avoid using it without losing that point. More obvious stuff. And I have to assume that things like "because" and "since" have long crossed the author's mind.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, and I'll see where I can use it.  However, I'm with Peter in that somethimes, there's a good reason to mark causality.  Often, I don't just write 'a, therefore b', but 'a, b, c, therefore d.'  Unless I mark it, the causal structure does not become clear from the sequential structure of the paragraphs.

Comment: a clear, logical and convincing answer.

Comment: I have to disagree. The logic in your examples is much less clear, because it's no longer clear whether the second sentences follow from the first ones or are additional claims, which would not be uncommon. The logic of "A. Also B. Therefore C." is quite different from that of "A. Therefore B. Therefore C." Scientific writing should strive for clarity. You don't want your reader to become hung up on what your reason for claiming "It can be assumed that neurons..." is. That said, if the implication is really very clear or direct, that's a different story.

Comment: I fully agree with @aes. While it is true that in a sequence of statements, each follows from *something*, it is not at all clear that it should follow from the previous statement. Maybe it is a general fact of life, or maybe it is mentioned half a page earlier. In scientific writing, it is (imho) best to make it as easy as possible to figure out why each statement is true, and omitting "thus" actually makes it more difficult.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @Peter on this one, if only because of [his algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) (and that I do agree, but that's less important)

Answer (score 2):

> Later in life, neural responses to sensory input become highly
>   differentiated, as do overt reactions. Because of this increased
>   differentiation, it can be assumed that neurons adapt their responses
>   mediated by experience...

Or

> Later in life, neural responses to sensory input become highly
>   differentiated, as do overt reactions. This increased differentiation
>   suggests that neurons adapt their responses mediated by experience...

That is, summarize the first sentence, or its essence, and express it as part of the second sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Don't write it, show it, were Francine Prose's words, I believe (albeit regarding prose writing).  However, if your argument form isn't the focus, then perhaps, by clearly describing the premise-consequence relationship in terms of the material itself, when possible, may help to engage the reader and keep them there.